# ol 6.9.0, cannot to create a production bundle

Tags: html-lists

Unable to follow instructions on
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html
so as to build the production bundle.
The developed application appears at http: // localhost: 3000 / not at http: // localhost: 1234 / as it is written.
And using the npm run build command, a functional production bundle is not created.

Answer (score 0):

The repository has been updated and mentioned [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/doc/tutorials/bundle.md) and quote:

> You can now visit http://localhost:3000/ to view your application.
> Begin making changes to the index.html and main.js files to add
> additional functionality.

You should go to github pages for the latest information instead of the site you are referencing.

GitHub Link: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers